# Cookie can't be set server-side with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, cookies

I use the simple way to create cookie but it just doesn't work.

My code is like this :

```
router.post('/auth', function(req, res, next){
    ...

       res.cookie('access_token', 'test')

       console.log(req.cookies)

    ...
})
```

I can get the token client-side. But the console.log says 'undefined'

Comment: Are you using `cookie-parser`  as a  middleware?

Comment: I don't use any tool. Is it inevitable?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I used library 'Cookies' from npm. It works fine.